# Java GUI stops responding when I click stop button that calls a thread to wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

When I click the stop button on my GUI which invokes the code below through an event listener, the GUI stops responding. I know wait() has to be synchronized, but what is the correct way to invoke it? Thanks in advance!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(actionEvent.getSource().equals(ui.stop)) {
            if(clickerThread != null) {

                /*terminate() stops the while loop 
                running in the thread's run(); */
                autoClicker.terminate();

                synchronized(clickerThread) {
                    try {
                        clickerThread.wait();
                        ui.updateLabel("Idle", ui.state);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is how the thread was created in case it helps:

```
else if(actionEvent.getSource().equals(ui.play)) {
            if(clickerThread == null) {
                autoClicker= new AutoClicker();
                clickerThread = new Thread(autoClicker);
                clickerThread.start();
                ui.updateLabel("playing", ui.state);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're finding out, calling `wait()` does not freeze the thread that it's called on (in fact it can be called on any "monitor" object -- thread or not), but rather the thread that its called **in**. Per the [Object API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (and do make it a habit to read the API before asking):

> Causes the **current thread to wait** until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.

Much better to give your clickerThread class a public method that the GUI can call that pauses and resumes execution. So perhaps you wish to give your clickerThread class a `volitile` boolean field that it checks when deciding whether to continue running or not, and then give the class a public method to set this field's value.